# RavenDb backup using HTTP API returns 401

Tags: ravendb

POSTing `"{ 'BackupLocation': 'C:\Backups\2010-05-06' }"` to http://localhost:8080/admin/backup using Fiddler results in a 401.

RavenDb is running as a service and `<add key="Raven/AnonymousAccess" value="All"/>` is set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alexander, please make sure that you're running the application that posts as administrator (either Raven.Backup.exe or the console).

Comment: Um... an application doesn't need admin rights to send an HTTP POST command.

Comment: No, but it needs them because RavenDB uses Windows Authentication to verify if the sender has permissions to initiate backups.

Comment: Thx. Initiating backups is a different permission then AnonymousAccess?

Comment: Yes. You need to have Administrator privileges, if you want to start a backup.

Comment: If you're using Fiddler you can also check the body of the 401 message. If I am right with this being an Administrator issue, the message will be 'Only administrators can initiate a backup procedure'

Comment: Why was this voted down?

Comment: There's no reason phrase using fiddler: 
HTTP/1.1 401 UnauthorizedContent-Length: 0

Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0

WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate

WWW-Authenticate: NTLMDate: Fri, 06 Apr 2012 19:29:34 GMT

Proxy-Support: Session-Based-Authentication

Comment: I believe it should be in the lower window on the right pane in fiddler. Anyway, can you try if it works when you start Raven.Backup.exe as administrator, which you will find in ravens install directory under /Backup ?

Comment: @ArnoldZokas that's probably because Chris misunderstood my answer.